# AVR Studio 5 can't connect to any programmer

Tags: avr

I am trying to use AVR Studio 5 to program an Atxmega64a1 with basic hello world code. I am using 64 bit win7. I have the chip plugged in to an STK600 to try and program it. When I go to tools>AVR Programming and select the tool, I see two options: Simulator and STK600 (with a long serial number after it). I set the tool to STK600 and select the proper Device, switch the interface to JTAG, and hit "Apply"

AVR Studio freezes for a moment and says:

"Unable to connect to tool STK600 (6&33ECC3F5&0&4)", with the following details:
Timestamp:  2012-01-19 20:04:38.771
Severity:   ERROR
ComponentId:    20000
StatusCode: 0

Unable to connect to tool context: 'Atmel.VsIde.AvrStudio.Services.TargetService.TCF.Internal.Services.Remote.ToolProxy+ToolContext'.

I hit close and after another few seconds get a second error:

"Failed to get JTAG daisy chain settings." with the following details:
Timestamp:  2012-01-19 20:07:59.057
Severity:   ERROR
ComponentId:    20000
StatusCode: 0

Unable to connect to tool context: 'Atmel.VsIde.AvrStudio.Services.TargetService.TCF.Internal.Services.Remote.ToolProxy+ToolContext'.

It's not this board because it works on a friend's computer, and I get the same error when using a JTAGICE MKII and even with a Dragon. Any idea what it might be? I have tried uninstall and re-installing absolutely everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much trial and error, it seems that USB 3.0 is incompatible with avr programmers. I switched USB ports to a 2.0 port and now it works beautifully!

Comment: saved me a lot of time just now :)

Comment: How do I upvote this more than once?  This has plagued me for some time and it never dawned on me to check usb port type (always assumed it was a board acting funky).  Muchas muchas gracias.